# jquery tokeninput with prepopulate not working

Tags: jquery

I use the following script:
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

But I can not use the " prepopulate "

Here's what I did:

```
    $("#select-countries").tokenInput("/api/countries", {   
    theme: "facebook",
    hintText: "Saisissez le nom de pays",
    noResultsText: "Aucun résultat",
    searchingText: "Chargement...",
    searchDelay: 200,
    minChars: 3,
    preventDuplicates: true,
    prePopulate: $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : "/api/countries",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            prepopulateWards.push({ id: data[j].id, name: data[j].name });
        }
    }),
    onResult: function (results) {
        $.each(results, function (index, value) {
            value.name = value.name;
        });

        return results;
    },
    onAdd: function (item) {
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" id="country-' + item.id + '" name="countries[]" value="' + item.id + '">');
    },
    onDelete: function (item) {
        $('#country-' + item.id).remove();
    }
});
```

But it does not work. An idea ?

Thank you

Comment: *It does not work* means that you have any errors on console? Did you see the network tab to see if the request is thrown?

Comment: prePopulate does not display data. 
the console does not display error. Api return [{id: 66, name: "France"}]
0
:
{id: 66, name: "France"}
id
:
66
name
:
"France"

Comment: Your prepopulate function only fills an array called `prepopulateWards` that's missing in the code. Why don't you add that result to the question?

Answer (score 0):

According with the official documentation (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#pre-populated) you are not returning anything to `prePopulate` property. My suggestion is to make this:

```
prePopulate: (function() {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url : "/api/countries",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    var prepopulateWards = []; // initialise the array
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        prepopulateWards.push({ id: data[j].id, name: data[j].name });
    }
    return prepopulateWards; // return to prePopulate property
  });

})(),
```

Example of code in the related documentation:

```
$("#demo-input-local").tokenInput(
  prePopulate: [
    {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
    {id: 11, name: "Python"},
    {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
    {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
    {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
    {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
    {id: 29, name: "C#"},
    {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
    {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
    {id: 41, name: "C"},
    {id: 43, name: "C++"},
    {id: 47, name: "Java"}
  ]
);
```

Comment: prePopulate: function() {
   $.ajax({
   type : 'get',
   url : "/api/countries",
   dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
   var prepopulateWards = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    prepopulateWards.push({ id: data[j].id, name: data[j].name });
   }
   return prepopulateWards;
  })
 },


It does not work in "Network" , I do not see the call to "/ api / countries"

Comment: Edited the answer :)

Comment: Ok , it goes well in the API now , but it still does not show results.

Comment: If i try : console.log(prepopulateWards); after "for", I see [Object]0: Objectid: 66name: "France"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]